# Problems with CloseMainWindow() to close a Windows Explorer window

Tags: c#, process, pinvoke

I´m facing a problem when trying to close a Windows Explorer (not Internet Explorer) window through another application, using the "Process.CloseMainWindow()" method; because it doesn´t close the Explorer window, it tries to close the full Windows (Operative System), by the way, Windows XP.

The code is as follows:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern UInt32 GetWindowThreadProcessId(Int32 hWnd, out Int32 lpdwProcessId);


    public String[] exeCommand()
    {

        try
        {
            //Get App
            Int32 hwnd = 0;
            hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
            Process actualProcess = Process.GetProcessById(GetWindowProcessID(hwnd));

            //Close App
            if (!actualProcess.CloseMainWindow())
                actualProcess.Kill();

        }
        catch { throw; }

        return null;

    }
```

Suppose that the "actualProcess" is "explorer.exe"

Any help will be appreciated!!
Salutes!

Comment: Explorer.exe can display many windows.  You'll need to narrow down in your question which particular one you might want to close.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because the main window for explore is considered the shell.  You can however kill the process, but windows will start it right back up.

Comment: The Kill method worked, it closed the Explorer window and it didn´t start it back, but i would like to know if there is a less critical way to close the Explorer windows.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish